# Replacing a cfl tube light with a led wiring help

Tags: led, light, replacement

So I was given the task of replacing old cfl tube lights in my room for brighter led (120 cm long) ones. Never done this before so I'd appreciate a walkthrough. I already took down the old tube light fixtures and all but can't tackle how to get the led put up. My first issue is wiring. Led has 2x0.75mm2 wire in it. Cables from wall are about just the same if not smaller. How do I connect those two? Mix and tape? Or a screw box connector thing? Is there any to dos with the ballast? Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately your message is so vague about the essential details that it will be difficult for us to answer.  Since you reveal so little, it's also difficult to gauge your level of experience with mains electrical, i.e. I don't know which knowledge gaps need filling. Mains electrical is lethal to the unawares.  I'm sure you don't want a 2-day side trip, but consider reading a book about DIY electrical thoroughly.  There's a fair bit you need to know.   Also which country?

Comment: Are you aware that there are drop-in LED replacement tubes available in many sizes of conventional fluorescent tubes? It sounds like you're attempting to rewire the fixtures but without any knowledge of how to do so.